# How to get locale of a Facebook Page's Posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've got a Facebook page that I would like to get all the posts from and for the users who have liked or commented on the posts within the page, I would like to get their locale information where available.

My slim down version of the code thus far is:

```
 <page_id>/feed?fields=likes{id,name},comments{id,from}&limit=1
```

which returns the likes and comments works but the only way to get their locale information seems to require another query per user to determine if their locale data is populated

```
 <user_id>?fields=locale
```

Given that the data is readily available (if the users has allowed it), is there any way to get this as part of a single query within the likes/comments area or within the summary (ideally)?

I've tried the following but doesnt appear to work

```
<page_id>/feed?fields=likes{id{locale},name}
```

Thanks